# How To Perform Segue After Picking Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I would like to perform a segue just after the user chooses an image (by clicking on the image view).

I have already checked the segue id and successfully managed to connect both view controllers.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // Executed when we select an image from the photo library.
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            // Sets the image to the image view (not really relevant because
            // we push the user to the DetailVC, but let's leave it).
            self.imageView.image = image

            // Closing the image picker.
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            // Performing segue (It doesn't perform!).
            print("It gets to this point, but doesn't perform.")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

The program sets the image to the image view, gets to that print statement just after the "perform" function, but the segue is not performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in storyboard select the view controller which has the imageview, at the top there is yellowcircle right click drag from there to the view controller you want to segue to and give its identifier an ID = “segueID”
then edit your didfinishpicking method like this

```
if let img = info[.originalImage] as? uiimage{
myimageview.image = img
dismiss(animated: true) {
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: “segueID”, sender: self)}}
```

Comment: It still does not perform the segue :/

Comment: how are you setting the segue in storyboard

Comment: My bad. It works smoothly now. Could you just clarify why I have to put the "performSegue" method inside the completion block?

Comment: as much as i know if you put something in the competionhandler it is called immediately before dismissing the view controller so if it is a heavy task you should not do it in here but since we want to go to new view controller we can do it here in the main queue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- Setting the sender to `self`?
- Making sure that your segue is the correct type. (I know you checked the name and you probably would have gotten an error if you got the name wrong, in this case I mean "push" vs "show detail" etc)
- Adding a `prepareForSegue` function to make sure that the segue is actually getting called

Comment: Yes. Same result :(

Comment: Still not working. I have even already tried with different types of segues and changing the segue id, but nothing yet.

Comment: Did you add the `prepareForSegue` and did it get called?

Comment: I had already added before, but the segue is still not performed. The only way the segue is activated is if I add a button.

Comment: But does prepareForSegue get notified that your segue is being performed or does it never get called. This could indicate that the segue is not reaching UIKit properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies that you are dismissing your view/view controller before performing segue

```
// Closing the image picker.
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have to close the image picker before going to the next view. If I remove this line, the image picker will never close.

Comment: If the segue is set up as "push" or "show", then it should replace it in the navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Building up on @Loren Rogers answer:

```
// Closing the image picker.
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You're not actually dismissing the `UIImagePickerController`. Like Loren mentioned, you're dismissing the `ViewController`. This is because `self` is a reference to the `ViewController`.

**Replace `self` with `picker` like so:**

```
// Closing the image picker.
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I changed 'self' to 'picker', and although the picker is dismissed, the segue is still not performed.